# Provision Azure AD Users to wso2 identity server using SCIM

Tags: azure, wso2, azure-active-directory, wso2-identity-server

In order to configure "Auto Provisioning" from Azure Active Directory to wso2 identity server/manager, Initial connection needed are as:- "Tenant Url" & "secret token".

Can you please let me know how to generate "Secret Token" in wso2 identity server and will it work with rest api for scim.

Ref: salesforce like application do provide secret token initially when account is setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any authentication mechanism to authenticate with WSO2 Identity Server SCIM endpoints such as basic auth,oauth. Please refer [1] for basic auth.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/SCIM+1.1+APIs

Comment: authentication for scim enabled wso2 identity server works fine for both basic auth and OAuth protocol. But, when connection details (using bearer token) is tried with Azure AD provisioning, it throws an error stating: "You appear to have entered invalid credentials. Please confirm you are using the correct information for an administrative account."

Is there any specific way or method ,say uri/ creds that should be used in case of scim connection from Azure AD to Wso2 IS.

Comment: Did u follow these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups ?

Comment: yes, I have followed this very document for testing." Test Connection queries the SCIM endpoint for a user that doesn't exist, using a random GUID as the matching property selected in the Azure AD configuration. The expected correct response is HTTP 200 OK with an empty SCIM ListResponse message".   If you take a look into this point, Azure is expecting HTTP 200 OK with empty SCIM list, if there is any configuration/workaround that can be implied to achieve the same, Probably this might work.